# Reading from XML file taking very long time

Tags: java, file-io, iostream, decode, decoding

I have encoded images into xml file and at the time of decoding I am experiencing problem of long execution time(almost 20 mins for moderate size image), Following code shows how I am now converting xml into string which is taking very long time for xml having large images, Is their any other way around to get xml into string in less time.

```
String s1= new String();
System.out.println("Reading From XML file:");
    InputStream inst = new FileInputStream("c:/collection.xml");
    long size = inst.available();
        for(long i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            s1=s1+ (char)inst.read();

        }
    inst.close();
```

Problem is worse when my xml contain multiple images.

Comment: ... btw, why are you reading an xml file into a string? just feed the `InputStream` to your parser - if your intesion is to parse the document -, no need to have the content in a `String` object.

Comment: Actually I am a student and I have been given such assignment. First I am reading in string then using Base64 to decode string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use StringBuilder instead of String s1. String concatenation `s1=s1+ (char)inst.read();` is the problem.

Another thing to fix - use `BufferedInputStream` because reading by byte from `FileInputStream` is extremely inefficient.

It is bad idea to use available, this is better

```
for(int i; (i = inst.read()) != -1;) {
    ...
}
```

all in all

```
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    try (InputStream inst = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:/collection.xml"))) {
        for(int i; (i = inst.read()) != -1;) {
            sb.append((char)i);
        }
    }
    String s = sb.toString();
```

and if file is small enough to fit into memory then

```
    File file = new File("c:/collection.xml");
    byte[] buf = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        in.read(buf);
    }
    String s = new String(buf, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: That will not have any effect. JDK will transform code from this example to StringBuilder-based, check generated bytecode.

Comment: should i use StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder(inst.read());

Comment: Why not to try the speed change?

Comment: StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder(); (instead of String s1 = new String) and s1.append((char)inst.read());

Comment: Evgeniy Dorofeev I tried that but its not working. I have checked in debug mode after axecuting above command s1 do not contain any data.

Comment: Evgeniy Dorofeev your solution really worked very smoothly, I going remember it for lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

1st

```
String s1= new String();
```

is useless since String is immutable and is assigned every loop iteration a new object (result of concatenation).

2nd, Use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build String using a loop

3rd, read using a byte buffer using [InputStream#read(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) or [InputStream#read(byte[], int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) it is much faster that reading byte by byte.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the `StringBuilder` solution suggested in previous answer, you can try different approaches to speed it up dramatically:

1. Use `BufferedInputStream`.
2. You know the file size. You can allocate a char buffer of file size and slurp the whole file content into it using `java.io.Reader.read(char[] buf)` method. Be careful about huge files; slurping huge files may make you run into OutOfMemoryException.
3. Use a XML parser to load XML content. They know how to read the file efficiently (oh, implementation dependent; better than the logic you used in any case). Be careful about DOM parsers; they may make you run into OutOfMemoryException if the file is huge. You may want to use SAX parser to get events of each image content being read so that you can handle them one at a time.